# Add css in HTML table?

Tags: html, css

I want to add `backbround-color` on third `tr` in `table`  using css not inline style.

Any one help me?

Below my html code:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>First TR</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Second TR</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Third TR</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Four TR</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Fifth TR</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Thanks

Comment: show us something you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
table>tbody>tr:nth-child(3) {
background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>First TR</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Second TR</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Third TR</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Four TR</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Fifth TR</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
tr:nth-child(3) {
    background-color: #ddd;
    /* Your css here */
}
```

Learn more about `nth-child` here: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-child/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with this selector:

```
table tr:nth-child(3){
   background-color: #rgb; /*your color */
}
```

> `:nth-child(n)` accepts a number and it is one based, i.e. first child
>   is accessed with `1`

Answer (score 0):

```
table tr:nth-child(3) {
    background: #ccc;
}
```

Working example http://jsfiddle.net/gqr3J/1602/